# How to add word to iOS text correction dictionary? Learn Spelling / Hide Red Squiggly Line

Tags: ios, pages, dictionary, spellcheck, spelling

I will often type a brand name or other word that the iOS text correction dictionary thinks is a typo or misspelled.

This adds a red squiggly line under the offending word. Screenshot from Apple iOS Notes app:

[image: iOS red squiggly line typo]

Tapping on the red word may suggest an auto-correction:

[image: ios correction red highlight]

Or if there are no suggestions, it says "No Replacements Found"

[image: No Replacements Found]

However there does not appear to be an option to remember this spelling for future uses. In Microsoft Word this was traditionally the "Add to Dictionary" menu item action.

In Apple's Pages app for macOS, this feature is called "Learn Spelling" and/or "Ignore Spelling":

[image: Learn Spelling macOS Pages]

How can I add a word to the iOS dictionary, or otherwise hide the red squiggly line under "misspelled" words that I want to use in the future?

Comment: You mean like this? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207767

Comment: @SteveChambers that seems to be for the dictionary "in Pages, Numbers, and Keynote". I'm using Notes.app and would like for the word to be recognized system-wide.

Comment: Read farther down, it gets into specifics on other apps and the OS itself.

Comment: @SteveChambers - this is why we like answers instead of links… your link is dead